# jQuery Programatically Effecting Div

Tags: jquery, variables, html, show

I'm working on a shopping cart for a client. We have up and down arrows next to product images to select the amount of an item you want to purchase. I'm trying to get this to automatically update the shopping cart also. So any item that has a value of more than one will automatically appear in the cart.

I have the up and down buttons working for each product but when I add in the code for the If statement it breaks everything. I'm also not sure I'm doing this properly because I would need an If statement for each product and there could be 70 products in the store.

Is there a way to use a variable in the If statement to get the matching cart div and make it show?

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/7XnXF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  You can use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a certain index and [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the current index.  Since you structured your `.cart_product` div according to your other `div` you can just get the current index of the clicked `div` and use that to show/hide the corresponding `div`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num;
    $('.up').click(function() {
        num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text());
        $(this).prevAll('.product').text(num + 1);        
        $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).show();// <-- on up click you will only ever show a product

    });

    $('.down').click(function() {
        num = parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text());
        if (num > 0) {
        $(this).siblings('.product').text(num - 1);
        }

        if (parseInt($(this).siblings('.product').text()) == 0) { <-- check if current val in div is == 0
            $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).hide(); <-- if it is the hide the .cart_product div with the same index as the current "div"
        } else {
            $('.cart_product').eq($(this).closest('.product_box').index()).show();
        }
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7XnXF/12/

Comment: I've using this code, how would I access another div inside the .cart_product div? I need to update the number of items so it matches the number of items on the left of the page. I've got a new jsfiddle to help explain. I added line 7 to the code but it's not correctly accessing the div I need to update. 

http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/MHMVC/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var num;
    $('.up').click(function() {
          num = parseInt($(this).prevAll('.product').text());
          $(this).prevAll('.product').text(num+1);
        });

    $('.down').click(function() {
          num = parseInt($(this).prevAll('.product').text());
          if(num>0){
          $(this).prevAll('.product').text(num-1);
          };
        });

        // Uncommenting these breaks everything
        if ($('#product_item_one').nextAll('.product').text(num > 0)){
            $('#cart_item_one').show();
        };

        if ($('#product_item_two').nextAll('.product').text(num > 0)){
            $('#cart_item_two').show();
        };

        if ($('#product_item_one').nextAll('.product').text(num <= 0)){
            $('#cart_item_one').hide();
        };

        if ($('#product_item_two').nextAll('.product').text(num <= 0)){
            $('#cart_item_two').hide();
        };

});​
```

Comment: That helped. The cart divs are always showing now though, even when the value of num is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code;

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var num;
     var $flag = 0;
     $('#cart_container').hide();
    $('.up').click(function() {
        $flag++;
          num = parseInt($(this).prevAll('.product').text());
          $(this).prevAll('.product').text(num+1);
          $('#cart_container').show();
        });

    $('.down').click(function() {
        $flag--;
          num = parseInt($(this).prevAll('.product').text());
          if(num>0){
          $(this).prevAll('.product').text(num-1);
          };
        if($flag < 1){
        $('#cart_container').hide();
        }
        });

        // Uncommenting these breaks everything
        if ($('#product_item_one').nextAll('.product').text(num > 0)){
            $('#cart_item_one').show();
        };

        if ($('#product_item_two').nextAll('.product').text(num > 0)){
            $('#cart_item_two').show();
        };

});
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7XnXF/10/)** is the fiddle.

Hope this helps...`:)`